# How can I escape characters such as hyphens (think of date format) that are stored within a Bash variable if I reference it in a 'printf' statement?

Tags: bash, escaping, printf

To clarify let me give an example. I have a csv file that I have parsed the columns of but when I try to reference the field that contains date (formatted as 15-Jun-2020) my printf statement does not know how to escape it:

```
#Example csv content/placement (IGNORES.csv): C330001000,R3343,15-Jun-2020

while IFS=, read -r field1 field2 field3;
do
        printf "UPDATE ODS.PERF_ACCT_ERR_DTL SET REC_ACTV_IND='T' WHERE BUS_DT='$field3' and ETL_ERR_CD='$field2' AND ACCT_KEY in (SELECT ACCT_KEY FROM ODS.ACCT_PORTFOLIO WHERE ACCT_SRCH_NBR='$field1');\nCOMMIT;\n"
done < IGNORES.csv > queryfile.sql
```

The output ends up looking like this:

```
' and ETL_ERR_CD='R3343' AND ACCT_KEY in (SELECT ACCT_KEY FROM ODS.ACCT_PORTFOLIO WHERE ACCT_SRCH_NBR='﻿C330001000');
COMMIT;
```

I tried some weird escape character combos I thought would help but so far the closest I've gotten is printing the whole thing but instead of it showing 15-Jun-2020 it shows field3 as the output. Any suggestions or references for understanding how to escape something stored within a variable?

Comment: The problem isn't `printf`, it's because your CSV file is in DOS/Windows format, and has a nonprinting carriage return character at the end of each line (in addition to the newline that unix programs expect), and it's getting treated as part of `field3`. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22481278/syntax-error-invalid-arithmetic-operator-error-token-is). In your case, you can trim it by changing the `read` statement slightly: `while IFS=$',\r' read -r ...`

Comment: BTW, you really shouldn't include data directly in `printf`'s "format string" (the first argument). Use `%s` as placeholder in the format string, and pass the data as separate arguments: `printf "UPDATE ODS.PERF_ACCT_ERR_DTL SET REC_ACTV_IND='T' WHERE BUS_DT='%s' and ETL_ERR_CD='%s' AND ACCT_KEY in (SELECT ACCT_KEY FROM ODS.ACCT_PORTFOLIO WHERE ACCT_SRCH_NBR='%s');\nCOMMIT;\n" "$field3" "$field3" "$field1"`

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate because I already answered your question about building the SQL request. and you did not even take time to apply sample, recommendations or even approve an answer there.

Answer (score 4):

## Replace the `-` with `\-`

If all you're dealing with is hyphens, you can use parameter substitution to do a find and replace.

```sh
var="15-Jun-2020"
${var//-/\\-}
```

### Breakdown

The `//` double forward slash indicates a global find and replace in a parameter substitution.

```sh
${var//PATTERN/REPLACEMENT VALUE}
```

Comment: bash's *pattern substitution* `${param/pat/string}` uses pattern matching as described in `man bash` (not regular expressions).

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62205458/building-sql-update-statements-using-a-bash-script/62205864#62205864

Answer (score 0):

The input file appears to be in Windows/DOS format. You can convert it with `dos2unix`. For more see *[wooledge - How do I convert a file from DOS format to UNIX format](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/052)*.

Use `printf` format argument correctly:

```
while IFS=, read -r field1 field2 field3
do
  printf '%s\n' "UPDATE ODS.PERF_ACCT_ERR_DTL SET REC_ACTV_IND='T' WHERE BUS_DT='$field3' and ETL_ERR_CD='$field2' AND ACCT_KEY in (SELECT ACCT_KEY FROM ODS.ACCT_PORTFOLIO WHERE ACCT_SRCH_NBR='$field1');" "COMMIT;"
done < IGNORES.csv > queryfile.sql
```

`%s\n` is a format argument - subsequent arguments will be printed according to this.

Comment: Why use `printf` if you don't even use it to format variables `$field1` `$field2` and `$field3`'s values properly within the SQL statements, using `%s` format tags within the `printf`'s format string?